# Numpy Average distance from array center

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have the center point of an array,

```
center_point = (array.shape[0]/2.,array.shape[1]/2.)
```

I have a binary image array, `array`, which has a shape whose relevant pixels are set to 0 (all other pixels are 255).

---

I need the average distance from the center of the array for all the pixels set to zero, and I need it to be vectorized (it can't be interpreted at the python level--way to slow).

Here is what I have, and now I am stuck, because the other answers I found point to SciPy, but the server **only** supports numpy.

```
centerpoint = array_center_point(shape_array)
distance_shape = np.zeros(size=shape_array.shape,dtype=float)

distance_shape[shape==0] = ...???

avg_distance = np.sum(distance_shape) / len(np.where(shape_array == 0)[0])
```

I can't figure out how to do this without making multiple calls to np.where and iterating through the shape indices with a python for loop.  There must be a way to get this done inside the numpy code...??

---

Here is the non-vectorized version that works:

```
def avg_distance_from_center(shape_array):
    center_point = array_center_point(shape_array)
    distance_shape = np.zeros(shape=shape_array.shape, dtype=float)

    shape_pixels = np.where(shape_array == 0)
    total_distance = 0.
    for i in range(len(shape_pixels[0])):
        i_ind = float(shape_pixels[0][i])
        j_ind = float(shape_pixels[1][i])

        total_distance += ((i_ind - center_point[0])**2.0 + (j_ind - center_point[1])**2.0)**0.5
    avg_distance = total_distance / len(shape_pixels[0])

    return avg_distance
```

Comment: Code up a working loopy implementation that we could try to vectorize?

Comment: @Divakar ok, will do... be a sec

Comment: If you say "only numpy" does that include cython (build dependency)?

Comment: @MSeifert  so basically, if the code has the header, `import numpy as np` it will run on the server.  Outside of that, I can't say.  Going to put up the loop version in a sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** With [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.sqrt(((np.argwhere(shape_array==0) - center_point)**2).sum(1)).mean()
```

**Approach #2 :** With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = (np.argwhere(a==0) - center_point)
out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs)).mean()
```

Comment: That's an amazingly clever use of `argwhere`, I wish I could upvote it more than once! However one note: I generally advocate `np.hypot` instead of `sqrt` and `square` because the implementation *may* be faster and it's *overflow* and *underflow* safe (in this particular case it's not important though).

Comment: @MSeifert Hmm I didn't know about the performance criteria with those alternatives, good to know! Good to see you pointing out those, thanks!

Comment: This is awesome and works for Manhattan distance from one index to all others:  `h_map[h_map==0] = np.abs((np.argwhere(h_map!=0) -
                              np.argwhere(h_map==100)).sum(1))`

Answer (score 3):

Just for illustration I use a random array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = (np.random.random((5, 5)) > 0.5).astype(int)
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> center = (2, 2)  # use your center here
```

To get the distances I will use a meshgrid:

```
>>> grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:arr.shape[0], 0:arr.shape[1]]
>>> grid_x
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
>>> grid_y
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

We shift the grid to the coordinates of the center:

```
>>> grid_x = grid_x - center[0]
>>> grid_y = grid_y - center[1]
```

Finally we calculate the distance using the `np.hypot` function (almost identical to `np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)`) but only using the points where `arr == 0`:

```
>>> distances = np.hypot(grid_x[arr == 0], grid_y[arr == 0])
```

And now it's time to calculate the mean/average of the distances:

```
>>> np.mean(distances)
2.767080465988093
```